# Android java AsyncTask return to class not method

Tags: java, android, list, class, android-asynctask

How do I return a list from AsyncTask to a class instead of a method?

I have this AsyncTask which connects to a webpage, reads the page into a string and then splits it all into variables. [This is the page](https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/commerce/listings/)

This is the AsyncTask:

```
public class sellableIds_AsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List> {

    String bodyHtml;
    List<String> items;
    private Context context;
    private sellableIdsFilter sellableIdsFilter;

    public sellableIds_AsyncTask(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void setSellableIdsFilter(sellableIdsFilter sellableIdsFilter) {
        this.sellableIdsFilter = sellableIdsFilter;
    }

    @Override
    protected List doInBackground(String... params) { //Incompatible return type
        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(params[0]);

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(get);
            bodyHtml = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()).replace("[", "");
            ;
            items = Arrays.asList(bodyHtml.split("\\s*,\\s*"));

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return items;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        this.sellableIdsFilter.sellableIdsFilter(result);
    }

    public interface sellableIdsFilter {
        public void sellableIdsFilter(List result);
    }

}
```

And called in the activity:

```
sellableIds_AsyncTask sellableIds_AsyncTask = new sellableIds_AsyncTask(this);
sellableIds_AsyncTask.setSellableIdsFilter(this);
sellableIds_AsyncTask.execute(sellableIdsUrl);
```

How can I return this list to the activity where I call it from and have the list able to use anywhere within the class? instead to the method `sellableIdsFilter();`

Comment: Pass your activty/fragment in the asynctask constructor, call the method of the activity/fragment in onPostExcute - done. Take care of removing references to it in onCancled()

Comment: @for3st How exactly do you do that? can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Create a listener  interface

```
public interface OnSellableIdsFilterListener {
    void onSellableIdsFilterSuccess(List<Integer> ids);
}
```

make the class you need to get the ids implement that interface

```
public class SomeClassThatNeedsTheIDs implements OnSellableIdsFilterListener {

    void someVoid() {

         //Pass the instance of this class to the constructor of the asynctask as a listener
        new YourAsyncTask(this, this).execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onGetSellableIdsFilterSuccess(List<Integer> ids) {
        // do whatever you want with the ids
    }


}
```

Change your asynctask adding a listener to the constructor

```
public class YourAsyncTask extends AsyncTask< , , > {

    Context context;
    OnSellableIdsFilterListener listener;

    public YourAsyncTask(Context context, OnSellableIdsFilterListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
        this.context = context;
    }

// In onPostExecute check if listener!=null and invoke the method, passing the ids

    public void onPostExecute() {
        if(listener!=null) {
            listener.onSellableIdsFilterSuccess(ids);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Where does `SomeClassThatNeedsTheIDs ` need to go? Or is that my acitvity?

Comment: This is your activity that needs to use the IDS

Answer (score 0):

You can add a method which returns List 'items' in your 'sellableIds_AsyncTask' class. After calling asyncTasks execute , call get() to ensure async task has finished its task. Then call the getter function to get your List 'items'. Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you elaborate more? I do not fully understand nor how to implement this,

Comment: Like any normal class this class can have getter function which returns list. In AsyncTask's case the only issue is a background thread is running so we need to wait till it completes the task. After the task is complete we have the desired list which we can get via the getter function we added. So , after calling execute(), call asyncTask's get() to ensure the thread completes it's work , then call your getter function to get the list.